# Return a subset of a List of objects in vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, list, lambda

I feel like there is a more simple way then anything I am thinking of right now to do this..

So I am going to lay some groundwork here:

- I have an Organization which has Departments stored as a List(of Department)
- The Departments has Person which is stored as a List(of Person)
- Each person has a Calendar in it which is a List(of Dictionary(String, String))

The short reason why is people do not want to upgrade to databases and I have to make do with pulling the data from an Excel table and manipulating the data to make a manning chart.

Now the issue I am having is that I need to scour the Organization across all Departments to select only Persons who's Calendar says they should be assigned to that Department for the day.

I can select their calendar status as follows:

```
If (person.Cal(dateOffset).Item("status") = Right(departmentName, 1) & ".") Then
```

So to make this more clear.. the calendar works as follows:
They select a date range in the GUI. The program finds the first date listed (a constant location in the Excel Table) and then does a date diff to get the dateOffset. That becomes the Excel Jump to number to lookup the dates. I am storing the cell color, cell text ("status") and cell comment in the Dictionary.

If they are assigned to a different department that day (where the departments could be DA, DB, DC, DD etc) they put A., B., C., D. and I have to parse the difference. Keep in mind this function works flawlessly. I am restructuring the code to make this dynamic and a lot less hard coded stuff as I have right now, a little less code, and less things running in memory.

Now the dilemma, the I need to access this information from the List and I'm hoping there is a way I don't have to do a for loop to do it since that is currently the way I am doing it. Is there a way to make a sub list from the full list of personnel that only returns people who's calendar status is equal to a value. I think the term is Lambda but whatever the term is I'm hoping for a solution like that. Thanks in advance.

Note: sorry I did not produce much code but there is a lot going on in there and the code is not releasable.

Comment: You can write a LINQ query, which will use Lambda expressions. The thing is, that will just be a way to make the code more succinct. It will still be effectively executing much the same loops as you would write yourself and will actually execute a bit slower, although the difference would not be noticeable. The thing is, if you just copy and paste a LINQ query that we write for you then you won't be able to maintain it. you should stick to loops for now and do some research to learn how LINQ works, then you can write queries that you will understand and we can help with specific issues.

Comment: I have done some myself. Not that I haven't but I'm completely spacing right now on verbiage since I don't use them often. Now that you said that I will also state execution time is why I am trying to improve this. The variables already existing are things like

Qualifications (there are 6 of them)
Departments (There are 13 of them with 4 being identified as critical and the others shift to support)
Components (There are 3 which identify different types of personnel)
Personnel (There are about 700 total)

Comment: Well-written LINQ code will almost always execute more slowly than the equivalent well-written non-LINQ code. If you're looking to improve execution time then LINQ is likely not the answer. You might need to look at optimising the code you have, if it's possible. The thing is, SO is not the place to ask for help optimising code that already works.

Comment: It may be that you need to look at putting all the `Person` objects into a single list at the start and then you can search that directly, without having to go through `Organization` and `Department`. Assuming that `Person` is a class, you can have the same objects be items in multiple collections, so they will be inherently synchronised.

Comment: I'm more looking for options I have. I gave an example. Problem is there were some big changes that have made this a little more necessary that I do not need to keep going in depth to change things. I'm fixing it so the configuration file (and later the options menu) can handle the entire problem. My situation is I am the only developer attached to the company. So things only move at my pace. Now don't get me wrong when I first received this is was horribly written and took an hour to produce the report needed. I have brought it down to approx 10 minutes by completely rewritting everything.

Comment: Though loops are for the most part unavoidable in this program I was hoping to reduce the number of them being executed. Which is by far the most impacting piece of the program

Comment: As I said, replacing a loop with a LINQ query simply makes the code more concise. Basically the same loop is still being executed behind the scenes. If you have written your loops well then replacing them with LINQ queries will be no help at all where execution time is concerned. If you haven't written them well then the solution is to write them better, not replace them with LINQ queries. If you just want to make your code more concise then LINQ is a good option as the increase in execution time will likely be negligible, but not if execution time is already an issue. LINQ is not magic.