# VB.NET Copy specific cell from selected Datagridview into a List of Long

Tags: vb.net, linq, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a datagridview that contains some 400,000 rows - where a user selects multiple rows, I'd like a list of long to be populated with a specific cell, from the selected rows i.e. a hidden primary key value that I have on the Datagridview.

I have got this far but I cannot seem to get it to work and I think that doing in via LinQ will be quicker than doing it as a For...Next or For...Each loop on selectedrows - especially if the user performs (and can and will) select 100,000+ rows - but my LinQ syntax is abysmal - so while I am here, if anyone has a great recommendation for LinQ that too, would be great (although there are books out there, nothing comes better than a recommendation from someone else who has read a few of them)

```
   Dim Mylist As New List(Of Long)

            Mylist.AddRange(DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).Select(Function(c) c.ColumnIndex(0).Value).ToList)
```

VS doesnt seem to like the c.ColumnIndex(0).Value

Comment: I quote @jmcilhinney "Well-written LINQ code will almost always execute more slowly than the equivalent well-written non-LINQ code." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739868/return-a-subset-of-a-list-of-objects-in-vb-net

Answer (score 2):

The property *SelectedRows* is a collection of *DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection*, not a collection of *DataGridViewCell*. So you should cast to the proper type, then you can use Linq to enumerate over a collection of *DataGridViewRow* that has the *Cells* property. This property is a collection of *DataGridViewCell*. Now you can use that collection as an array and use your index to reach the proper column.
Finally don't rely on automatic type conversion provided by VB.NET. I suggest to always be explicit in your conversions. Use Conver.ToInt64 or Int64.Parse

```
Dim result = DataGridView1.SelectedRows.
                           Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).
                           Select(Function(c) Convert.ToInt64(c.Cells(0).Value)).
                           ToList()
```